# Attempting to create a very simple JavaScript function that adds 7 to the user's inputted number

Tags: javascript, function, console

I'm trying to create a function that will take the user's inputted number and simple add 7 to it in JavaScript. I'm doing this in the console on my Firefox browser. I get the prompt as expected but after that it just displays undefined, I can't understand why. I tried to change the parameter to just the number variable but that didn't work out. Here's my code:

```
 var number =prompt("Pick a number");
 function add7(NewNumber){
 NewNumber = 7 + number;
 return (NewNumber);
 }
```

Comment: `prompt` returns a String, you'll have to convert it to a Number before : `let number = +prompt("Pick a number");`

Comment: How are you calling `add7`?

Comment: Seriously, I do not see a function call anywhere

Comment: Check out this callback function in use with prompt - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add7(){
    return parseInt(prompt("Pick a number"))+7;
 }
 add7();
```

`prompt()` returns a string so you first have to parse that value.

I have also removed unnecessary assignments from your code.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be most efficient method

Answer (score 1):

You should call your function like below.

```
function add7(number) {
  number = number + 7;
  console.log(number);
}

add7(3);
```

Comment: don't add numbericals as function/class/variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to an integer.

```
   var number =prompt("Pick a number");
     function add7(NewNumber){
     NewNumber = 7 + parseInt(number);
     return (NewNumber);
    }
```

If you paste this example directly into your browser console window, it should give you the desired effect.

```
var number = prompt("pick a number")

function add7(NewNumber){
  NewNumber = 7 + parseInt(number);
  return (NewNumber);
}

console.log(add7(number))
```

Comment: You also need to account for if your going to allow floats, and not just whole numbers. You'll probably also want to use a regex to ensure that the string only contains a number.

Comment: Yup. It works. Hes not probably implementing it in the best manner, but with what he provided this works.

Comment: Ha, this edit is what I wanted. There was not function call earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You should prompt inside the function, not outside

Also you don't need to pass any parameters to that function:

```js
function add7(){
        var number =prompt("Pick a number");
        var NewNumber = 7 + parseInt(number);
        return (NewNumber);
}
add7();
```